# Tooltip on custom shipping method

Tags: shipping

I am trying to figure out how to apply a dynamic tooltip for a specific custom shipping method. I need to show in the tooltip the separate charges that calculate the total shipping cost. For instance we have a service charge, an import fee, etc. I cannot find (being new to magento development) on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you'd need to modify a few things:

1. The rate data returned by your custom shipping method's implementation of `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierInterface::collectRates`. Magento by default just returns the complete price (with and without tax), but not individual fees.
2. Create an after plugin for `\Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter::modelToDataObject` to add that data to the shipping method data object. You will want to add that data to the extension_attributes array as to comply with the interface as defined here: `\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterface`
3. You'll need to modify the frontend template so that this data is displayed where you need it to be displayed. This should be done in your custom theme in: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`

**Edit:**
*Answering the question of how I knew `\Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter::modelToDataObject` had to be changed*

During checkout Magento may call one of the various different API methods to calculate shipping. See, for example, vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/webapi.xml:109

```
<route url="/V1/carts/:cartId/shipping-methods" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Quote\Api\ShippingMethodManagementInterface" method="getList"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Magento_Cart::manage" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

The implementation of that interface model is `\Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement::getList` which calls `$this->converter->modelToDataObject`

```
$shippingRates = $shippingAddress->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
foreach ($shippingRates as $carrierRates) {
    foreach ($carrierRates as $rate) {
        $output[] = $this->converter->modelToDataObject($rate, $quote->getQuoteCurrencyCode());
    }
}
```

`$this->converter` is \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter

Actually when you look at a few other methods that have to do with shipping calculations you'll see that conversion performed there as well.

Comment: And another question though, how did you know that after the collectRates method is goes to `\Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter::modelToDataObject` ?

Comment: when i have added get and set methods , i have added "->setShippingMethodTooltip('test')" in \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter::modelToDataObject but it in console it is throwing 500 service error